# "Question needs 0 votes to close", but I didn't cast a close vote

Tags: bug, flagging, vote-to-close

I just flagged [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/554021/use-official-flash-plugin-to-present-a-swf-file) as off-topic in /review, and got the popup

> This question still needs 0 vote(s) from other users to close

I don't have 3000 rep; I *didn't* vote to close, just flagged it. Moreover, it isn't closed (I just checked). What gives?

Comment: Possibly related to something I ran into on Stack Overflow....http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157241/188613

Comment: Can you repro right now?

Answer (score 1):

Still needs 2 votes as of this posting. Could be a bug.

Comment: I didn't even cast a vote; I don't have high enough rep.